# Angular form gathering data in wrong format

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor, angular-forms, json-server

I have data coming in from a json server that gets displayed exactly how I want and expect, but when saving changes, it doesn't save in the same format that it came in.

Here is my form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="saveProfile(form.value, form.valid)" #form="ngForm" novalidate>
  ...
  <input 
    matInput 
    placeholder="Company Name" 
    type="text"
    name="companyName"
    required
    #companyName="ngModel"
    [ngModel]="profile?.companyName">

  <!-- Code in question below: -->
  <ul class="days-of-operation">
    <li *ngFor="let day of profile?.daysOfOperation">
      <mat-checkbox
        [name]="day.day"
        [ngModel]="day.open">
        {{day.day}}
      </mat-checkbox>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ...
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">
    Update Profile
  </button>
</form>
```

Here is the working JSON that comes in:

```
{
  "profile": {
  "companyName": "Example Company",
    "daysOfOperation": [
      {
        "day": "Sunday",
        "open": false
      }, {
        "day": "Monday",
        "open": true
      }, {
        "day": "Tuesday",
        "open": true
      }, {
        "day": "Wednesday",
        "open": true
      }, {
        "day": "Thursday",
        "open": true
      }, {
        "day": "Friday",
        "open": true
      }, {
        "day": "Saturday",
        "open": true
      }
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Here is the data that `form.value` sends to the `saveProfile` method when I click the update button:

```
{
  "companyName": "Example Name",
  "Sunday": false,
  "Monday": true,
  "Tuesday": true,
  "Wednesday": true,
  "Thursday": true,
  "Friday": true,
  "Saturday": false
}
```

As you can see, the form is gathering the data in a completely different format. This works for `companyName`. I can change that to anything I want, save it, and it will come back the way I saved it, but the days aren't being passed in inside the `daysOfOperation` object anymore. Why is the form sending the data differently than it brought it in? How do I get it to save in the same format as it came in? What am I doing wrong?

I'm open to changing how I format the days of operation if that will make things better/easier.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking `form.value`, you can simply bind to the existing object, and use `this.profile`:

Change the `ngModel` like so:

```
  <mat-checkbox
    [name]="day.day"
    [(ngModel)]="day.open">
    {{day.day}}
  </mat-checkbox>
```

And in your `saveProfile`, just use `this.profile`, like so:

```
saveProfile() {
  console.log(this.profile)
}
```

[Here is a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knabnl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I'm trying to maintain one-way data flow and emit events when I'm ready to save changes. Is there an easy way to do this with checkboxes that are in a for loop?